# Rails generator m.directory returns can't convert nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

I have written this generator code but it returns 'can't convert nil into String' when I call m.directory inside the manifest. Anyone know what had happened?

```
class AuthGenerator < Rails::Generator::NamedBase
  attr_reader :user_class_name
  def initialize(runtime_args, runtime_options={})
    @user_class_name="User"
    @controller_class_name="AccountController"
    @user_class_file_name="#{@user_class_name}.rb"
    @controller_class_file_name="#{@controller_class_name}.rb"
  end

  def manifest
    record do |m|
      m.class_collisions @controller_class_name, @user_class

      puts @user_class_name
      m.directory File.join('app/models', @user_class_name)


    end
  end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Where is it choking?  Please post the full error.  You can see the source of the `directory` method [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generator/Commands/Create.html#M001866).

Plus, you probably just want

```
m.directory File.join('app/models')
```

Having an app/models/user directory for your generated code is not standard -- unless you're intending namespacing, which it doesn't look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialize method needs a call to super.